# Incrementing a uint8_t variable, strange outcome

Tags: c++

In a C++ class I've the following code/while loop:

```
uint8_t len = 0;

while (*s != ',') {
    len = (uint8_t)(len + 1u);
    ++s;
}
return (len);
```

The outcome should be a value between 0 and max 20.
As I receive a strange outcome, and started debugging. When I step through this
I get the following values for the variable Len:

‘\01’, ‘\02’, ‘\03’, ‘\04’, ‘\05’, ‘\06’, ‘\a’, ‘\b’, ‘\t’

I don’t understand the change from ‘\06’ to ‘\a’!

Can somebody explain this? I expect that the Len value is simply increased by 1 until character array pointer s hits the ',' char.

Comment: What's `s` in your code?

Comment: What problem are you trying to avoid by not writing `len++` or `++len`?

Comment: len++ I've tried as well but gave the same result. I though it was a casting problem hence I tried the example code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are correct, but your debugger interprets them as `char` type, not an integer type.

You can see [escape sequences used in C++ here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) (and the corresponding values in ASCII).

`\01` - 1 in octal, 1 in decimal
`\02` - 2 in octal, 2 in decimal
...
`\06` - 6 in octal, 6 in decimal
`\a` - equivalent to `\07`, the ASCII code to use the computer bell
`\b` - equivalent to `\010` (10 octal, 8 decimal), the ASCII code for "backspace" character
`\t` - equivalent to `\011` (11 octal, 9 decimal), the ASCII code for tabulator
etc.

I don't know if you can change the way your debugger interprets the data. Worst case, you can always print the value after casting it to `int`.

```
(gdb)p static_cast<int>(len)
```